# Ruby on Rails link_to internal id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

How do i use a link_to inorder to go to a specific (html) ID on a page normally
if i wanted to go to the "whatever_id" on a page i could use

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/index/mypage#whatever_id>Click Here</a>
```

but i would like to use my link_to

```
<%= link_to "click here" , {:action => "mypage", :controller => "index" }, :id => "#whatever_id"%>
```

helper methods. Does anyone know how to do this? Is it possible?

Rails 2.3.4

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*link_to* can add anchors to a URL.

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001597),

```
link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, :anchor => "wall")
# => <a href="/profiles/1#wall">Comment wall</a>
```

In your case you probably want,

```
 <%= link_to "click here" , {:action => "index", :controller => "mypage", :anchor => "whatever" } %>
```